# Howto get ID on newly created content through Drupal 8 REST POST

Tags: 8

I have a working decoupled/headless setup working using Drupal 8 beta 10 as a backend, and a html5/js webapp as frontend, on seperate servers.

For this scenario, I'm succesfully able to post new content (an article node) as an anonymous user, using the REST /entity/node endpoint.

This works fine, I receive a 201 "Created" response, but now I'm trying to figure out a way to get the ID of this newly created node so I can GET and render it.

The current [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2098511) and response does not provide a return (N)ID. Am I overlooking something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the response code for POST requests](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/rest/src/Plugin/rest/resource/EntityResource.php#n111), we can see that there's no body but a header set to the full URI of the node. You can save that URI or explode it/parse it to get just the nid.

```
  // 201 Created responses have an empty body.
  return new ResourceResponse(NULL, 201, array('Location' => $entity->url('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])));
```

Comment: Hmmm, yes, but that seems a bit dirty :(

Comment: In this context you are supposed to save the full uri anyway, it's the only way to uniquely identify a remote resource isn't it? This or a GUID + base url.

Comment: Drupal 8 does use UUID's so that would be an option.